# SharePoint Online, Image library, check if image Rendition exists (is generated)

Tags: image-rendition, thumbnail

Is there a flag that shows that image Rendition (thumbnail) is generated?
I have a library and some large files (more than 2Mb) does not have renditions generated. I do Preview feature and want to check if this image exists or not..

In SharePoint  Online You can see thumbnails and urls here:

[image]

upd.: I found "PreviewExists" flags, but actually there is no preview (for example for large > 60Mb *.tif files):

[image]

so I cannot use these flags..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally disabled preview for all files larger than ~10Mb. It looks like other files have preview..
I use CSR so part of code is:

```
                    View: function (ctx) {

                        try {
                            var imageUrl = ctx.CurrentItem.FileRef + "?RenditionID=1";
                            var fileSize = ctx.CurrentItem.File_x0020_Size;

                            if ((parseInt(fileSize, 10) > 10000000)) {

                                return ("<img src='/SiteAssets/nopreview.png' alt='No preview available'></img>");

                            } else {

                                return ("<img src='" + imageUrl + "' alt='Image preview'></img>");
                            }

                        } catch (ex) {

                            console.log("Exception: " + ex);
                            return "";
                        }
                    }
```